# maximum recursion depth exceeded, overriding methods in new class under UserList

Tags: python, class, recursion, iterator, overriding

I am creating a new class in UserList, and trying to override the **add**, append, and extend methods so that duplicate values will not be added to the list by any of these operations. So far I have started with trying to override the append method and when I try to implement the class on an object I get the error: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Here's what I have so far:

```
from collections import UserList

class UList(UserList):
  def append(self,item):
      for s in self:
          if item == s:
              print ("Item already exists in list")
          else:
              self.append(item)


x = [1,2,3,4,5]
z = UList(x)
print (z)
z.append(1)
```

Comment: what do you think `self.append(item)` does? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, think about it. You're already in `self.append()`. And then you call `self.append()`. This is a recursion and the next time through the code, nothing has changed (the item is still not in the list) so you recurse *again* and then again and then again and eventually, Python runs out of stack space to store the state of your recursion and you get the error.

Don't call `self.append()`. You have to call the base class method, since yours *can't do the append.*

```
def append(self, item):
    for s in self:
        if item == s:
            print ("Item already exists in list")
        else:
            UserList.append(self, item)
```

You can also use `super()` for this but it's not strictly necessary in this case; `super()` is vital in multiple-inheritance scenarios but in simpler situations, I find explicitly calling the base class is clearer.

Another point is that iterating over the whole list to see whether your item is in it is wasting time. Instead just do:

```
def append(self, item):
    if item in self:
        print("Item already exists in list")
    else:
        UserList.append(self, item)
```

You might also reconsider printing an error in your `append()` method. It would be better to raise an exception so that the code that's using your class can detect the error and handle it as desired. You can also make the error message more descriptive so it says *what* duplicate item was found.

```
def append(self, item):
    if item in self:
        raise ValueError(repr(item) + " already exists in list")
    else:
        UserList.append(self, item)
```

You might also just consider using a `set()` if you don't need to maintain the order. It doesn't store duplicates, so you can just add items and you will never get a duplicate; you don't have to check first.

Comment: thanks for your answer it makes sense. When i tried to implement your solution with raising an exception, it seems to raise it even when I try to append an item that does not exist in the list? --nevermind i see what I did wrong

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the same method recursively, call baseclass's `append` method to prevent the infinite recursion:

Py2.x:

```
super(UList, self).append(item)
```

Py3.x:

```
super().append(item)
```

Use `in` operator instead of looping through the whole list to check the existence of an item.

#### code:

```
from collections import UserList

class UList(UserList):
  def append(self, item):
      if item in self:
          print ("Item already exists in list")
      else:
          super(UList, self).append(item) # just `super().append(item)` in py3.x
```

Comment: +1 because `super()` is the correct way to cass base-class methods, but since the OP is using Python 3 (`UserList`), you should use the no-arg form of `super()`.